# What does "compression of spreads on high-yield debt" mean?

Tags: bonds, terminology, yield, spreads

What did Federal Reserve Chair Janet Yellen mean when she said the following?

> "We’ve also seen the compression of spreads on high-yield debt, which
>   certainly looks like a reach for yield type of behavior."

[Source](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/05/06/us-usa-fed-yellen-idUSKBN0NR1JI20150506)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/high-yield-bond-spread.asp) does a perfectly fine job of explaining it:

> The percentage difference in current yields of various classes of high-yield bonds (often junk bonds) compared against investment-grade corporate bonds, Treasury bonds or another benchmark bond measure.

So ... if a lot of people are buying junk bonds (i.e. **reach[ing] for yield**), those bonds' prices go up (due to supply-and-demand) and their yields go down (by definition), meaning the difference (**spread**) between investment-grade bond yields (which have presumably not changed) and junk bond yields is reduced (**compressed**).

Therefore, the compression in the yield spread means that a lot of people are so hungry for high returns that they're ignoring the high risk of junk bonds and buying them anyway.